# How can i serialize property of c# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, properties

I think it's inefficient to implement these two lines of variables.

```cs
[SerializeField] private int i;
public int I => i;
```

So I would like to express this in one line, but this is not serialized in Unity.

```cs
[SerializeField] public int I { get; private set; }
```

I want to make it visible in Unity Inspector.

So my question is below.

1. Can this property be serialized?
2. If impossible, is it possible to solve it in a way other than the above?

Comment: `SerializeField` actually serves three purposes.  **1)** removes the need for `public` fields.  Before then, all fields had to be public to be visible in the Editor **2)** makes `private` fields visible in the Editor **3)** ensures that the `private` field is serialised.   Unity generally does not care about public properties and won't show them in the Editor (unless you are using the problematic `field:`).   Remember, you are using Unity, a middleware and CLR Host, so typical C# best practices don't apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in C# 7.3 (which Unity supports), you can now add attributes to the backing fields generated by autoproperties.

For this instance, where the backing field is auto generated, you can add this attribute:

```
[field: SerializeField] public int MyField { get; private set; }
```

This serializes the backing field as if it were a normal variable.

Comment: Interesting.  Does Unity still put noise in the Editor though?  https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-7-3-field-serializefield-support.573988/

Comment: @Deleted put it into Unity and try? ^^ => No it doesn't, it needs to have a `set` though otherwise it is not serialized again

Comment: That seems beyond the normal engine flow Isn't it dangerous to "force" it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's correct behavior.

```
[SerializeField] 
public int I { get; private set; }
```

This is a *property* (with a getter and setter accessor), not a variable. These are not, cannot and should not be serialized. If you want an exposed variable that you can set (or see) in the Inspector, use a `public` modifier on a variable, not a function or accessor. If you don't want the variable to be public, then it can be `protected` or `private`, but marked with `[SerializeField]` as you already know. This is by design and is the correct approach.

*Some additional information as it seems you might have different expectations on how Unity should behave:*

Unity has *some* different paradigms as opposed to conventional programming and this is by design as the engine has a different approach to how each game object (and by this I mean any `UnityEngine.Object` descendant, not just `UnityEngine.GameObject`) interacts with another and how it should be implemented in the game (i.e. adding it as a `Component` or `ScriptableObject` as opposed to using `new()` or how the garbage collection of said objects is handled in the engine). This means that if you want the convenience of the Inspector real-time editing features, you'll need to "break" some rules regarding object access and mark a lot of variables as `public`. If you don't want that, there's always the option of referencing them in code or using `ScriptableObject`s, but that might be overkill in some cases.

Unity is also akin to encapsulated, as extending existing deployments is done differently from C#, so using public or private variables or functions doesn't change much. It's not like somebody is going to make a library and extend from your game's library since Unity doesn't work that way.

Comment: They can ;) See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74805528/7111561)